# Is underlayment necessary for laminate over dricore?

Tags: laminate-floor, underlayment

We have new dricore subflooring in a basement that is partially above and partially below grade.  There have been minor water seepages in the past thru the slab, which is why we put in the dricore.

We are nearly to the "install flooring" stage and are questioning the need for underlayment in our situation.  Underlayment is usually used, as I understand it, for:

1. Noise reduction
2. Moisture/vapor protection
3. Insulation? (maybe)

In our case the dricore is dricore+ which has an R-3 rating and acts as a vapor and moisture barrier.  Since it's in the basement, noise reduction is less of a concern.

So I'm thinking minimal underlayment - at most.  But is it necessary?  Or can we apply direct to the subfloor without concern?

[The specific product is](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Home-Legend-Wire-Brushed-Oak-Havana-3-8-in-T-x-5-in-W-x-Varying-Length-Click-Lock-Hardwood-Flooring-19-686-sq-ft-case-HL151H/204362337) Wire Brushed Oak Havana 3/8 in. T x 5 in. W x Varying Length Click Lock Hardwood Flooring

[image]

Comment: That depends completely on the product and your personal standards for sound. Undamped laminate can sound quite tappy.

Comment: Well, my mom (who will be living on that level once we finish building out her kitchen) is pretty hard of hearing ...

Comment: Added specifics on the flooring

Comment: As that product apparently doesn't require an underlayment the question becomes subjective, but you probably wouldn't see much benefit.